# Changing Layout after 5 seconds

Tags: java, android

My app starts by showing a layout that only contains my app icon and after 5 seconds it is supposed to switch to another layout I defined as another XML Layout file but when I test it on my phone the first layout shows and after 5 seconds the app exits . Below is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Timer timer;
    timer=new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.signup);}  },5000);}}
```

I've used timer function . activity_main is the layout xml file that contains the image view only and sign_up is the layout xml file containing signup forms.

I've seen the same thing in youtube but the guy changes the layout after button click and it worked .... I've only changed button click to timer.

Humbly requesting answers . Thank You

Comment: You need to run the `setContentView` in the UI Thread. You could wrap it in `runOnUiThread`. See the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) for more infos.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any view from layout activity_main to call postDelayed, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.tvHellow).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

and it works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . What is the tvHellow?

Comment: it is just textView from activity_main with id="@id/tvHellow". you can use any view you want from activity_main, becouse any view already has own handler under the hood

Answer (score 0):

you can also use handler like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           setContentView(R.layout.signup);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: you could use handler from any exisisting view from the layout

Comment: Thank you for this answer...It worked and was able to learn handler ,looper and threads